# Can't Get Node From GraphEdit Connection List

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm trying to get the values of some TextEdits within some Godot GraphNodes. This is what I've tried so far:

```
func _on_compile_pressed():
    var graph = $GraphEdit
    var connection_list = graph.get_connection_list()
    print(connection_list)
    
    var node_index = 0
    for node in connection_list:
        var value = graph.get_node(node["from"]).get_node("TextEdit").get_selected_text()
        print(graph.get_children())
```

When I run this it breaks because it's looking for a `NodePath` rather than a string. I'm not sure how I should be writing this to be able to either grab the correct NodePath or directly grab the node from the name in the connection dictionary.

I've been following this tutorial loosely:
https://youtu.be/AX5pN3mwfBc?t=533

However, this method doesn't seem to work in Godot4.

Any ideas for how this should work now?

Answer (score 1):

Let us see, you get a `GraphEdit` and get is connection list:

```
var graph:GraphEdit = $GraphEdit
var connection_list := graph.get_connection_list()
```

Then you iterate over the connection list... In which case you do this:

```
for connection_index in connection_list.size():
    var connection := connection_list[connection_index]
    # …
```

However, since you are not using it, I'll go ahead with this:

```
for connection in connection_list:
    # …
```

We can now read the `name`s of the `GraphNode`s that are connected:

```
for connection in connection_list:
    prints(connection["from_node"], connection["to_node"])
```

These are not `NodePath`s, they are `StringName`s, and Godot won't convert them automatically. So we do this:

```
for connection in connection_list:
    var from_path := NodePath(connection["from_node"])
    var to_path := NodePath(connection["to_node"])
    prints(graph.get_node(from_path), graph.get_node(to_path))
```

And from there you can proceed as you were:

```
for connection in connection_list:
    var from_path := NodePath(connection["from_node"])
    var value = graph.get_node(from_path).get_node("TextEdit").get_selected_text()
    prints(value)
```